# New to Python trying re. Why findall is not searching to end of line and matching ALL group of digits

Tags: python, python-2.7

A simple re to match numbers on a line would be:

```
/[0-9]+/gm
Will match (------> Match)
t1est ------->1
23    ------->23
foo
bar
304958    ------->304958
bar
as 4497 our 6702 personal 8454 assistants who can take care of many things    -----> 4497 6702 8454
```

When I try to do the same using python my program matches only the first occurrence of set of digits, seems after a match is not going to the rest of the line so is only obtaining the first match per line. I need all matches (all group of digits) per line.
Here is my code:

```
import re
hand = open('sum1.txt')
numlist = list()
for line in hand:
        line = line.rstrip()
        stuff = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
        if len(stuff) == 0  : continue
        numbers = int(stuff[0])
        numlist.append(numbers)
print 'Max ',max(numlist)
print 'Min ',min(numlist)
print 'Sum ',sum(numlist)
print numlist
```

Extraction from  the file reading:

```
"...
Conversing with Python

1052 Now that we have a word and a simple sentence that we know in Python, 8135
we need to know how to start a conversation with Python to test 
our new language skills.

Before 5561 you 517 can 1218 converse with Python, you must first install the Python
 software on your computer and learn how to start Python on your 
computer.  That is too much detail for this chapter so I suggest
that you consult www.pythonlearn.com where I have detailed
instructions and screencasts of setting up and starting Python 
on Macintosh and Windows systems.  At some point, you will be in 
a terminal or command window and you will type python and 
8877 the Python interpreter will start executing in interactive mode
and appear somewhat as follows:
interactive mode
..."
```

See the code once ran, it will match only the first group of digits see th output:

```
$ python myfirstdatapython.py
Max  9703
Min  5
Sum  244547
[3036, 4497, 7449, 3665, 7114, 956, 8003, 6662, 6482, 9634, 8805, 9703, 2834, 7221, 2981, 5415, 6872, 4806, 5460, 3538, 9663, 8752, 4509, 1004, 4034, 3482, 1052, 5561, 8877, 8062, 279, 2054, 918, 8687, 7073, 2923, 8824, 1079, 5, 2572, 5616, 9552, 829, 6015, 9548, 8402, 42]
```

Analysis :
See above 5561, 8877, it jumps from 5561 skips 517 and 1218 
What is wrong my push on the array?
Or should I improve regular expression.
Note : must use re.

Thanks!

Comment: 'cos you're deliberately only taking the first number and ignoring the rest in `numbers = int(stuff[0])` ?

Comment: @Jon thanks! will see how I lopp to add if more than one

Comment: Hint - `re.findall` already returns a `list` containing all the matches... go from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but here's a solution and what's happening...

```
import re

# don't use `list()` here - use `[]` an empty list
numlist = []
# We can use a with statement here so the file automatically
# closes on an error or when the block ends...
with open('sum1.txt') as fin:
    # iterate line by line
    for line in fin:
        # Get all the numbers as strings
        nums = re.findall('\d+'), line)
        # Convert to actual integers
        nums = [int(n) for n in nums]
        # Add them to the end of our list
        numlist.extend(nums)

# now do some work with `numbers`
# ...
```

Comment: Wow just starting out with Python and is blowing my mind. Thanks Jon for taking the time to comment the code and provide a solution.

Answer (score 2):

They're skipped because you tell Python to skip them:

```
    numbers = int(stuff[0])
    numlist.append(numbers)
```

`stuff` is your array of ALL matched numbers for the line being analyzed, but you only ever extract the first one (`[0]`) and save it, which essentially ignores/deletes all other subsequent numbers on that line.

Comment: @Mark thanks! will see how I lopp to add if more than one, first time I use stack too, I guess my question is answered.